# git: Error: Another active Homebrew process is already in progress

Tags: homebrew

When I try to do anything with `Homebrew`, I get the following error and don't know how to resolve it.
I run: `brew update`

I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/lock.sh: line 19:/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/update: Permission denied
    -e:1:in 'initialize': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
        from -e:1:in 'new'
        from -e:1:in '<main>'
    Error: Another active Homebrew process is already in progress. 
    Please wait for it to finish or terminate it to continue.
```

Comment: What is the output of `ps aux | grep brew`?

Comment: `myUsername      1017   0.0  0.0  2453272    836 s002  S+    1:52PM   0:00.00 grep brew`

Comment: See my answer on another thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39812903/875978

Answer (score 21):

That's probably because another instance of Homebrew crashed and left a lock file. You can delete it manually by deleting all files in the lock directory with :

```
rm $(brew --prefix)/var/homebrew/locks/*
```

Comment: Better: `rm $(brew --prefix)/var/homebrew/locks/*` (in case Homebrew configured to use different directories). The `brew(1)` manual page says Intel/Arm MacOS and Linux each have distinct configuration for Homebrew's install path.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by rm -rf /usr/local/Library/Locks/*